# Updating Vue Data Object Off AJAX response

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

What I am trying to do is loading a template using AJAX and then building a data model from an AJAX JSON response.  I want it to be reactive.  From what I've read on the Vue documentation, all the instance object properties have to be set at initialization for them to be reactive.  I was curious how I could go about doing that.

I am generating the object **model** based off an array of dot notation strings, converting a csv file to JSON, then parsing that data into the new **model** object.  This is how I envision the process

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            model: {}
        };
    }
});


/**
   -Load template, 
   -build model object, 
   -update Vue data, 
   -have template react to new data
*/
$(function() {

    // Load in html
    $(#model).load('./template.html', function(response, status, xhr) {

        var modelStructureAsArray = [
            'meta',
            'data',
            'data.details'
        ];

        // Update Vue data for model
        vm.model = buildObjectByArray(modelStructureAsArray);

        /**
        // Expected structure
          vm.model = {
            meta: {
            },
            data: {
                 details: {
                 }
            }
          }
        **/

       // This would be where I set all the data, im using a function to parse and 
       // return a full model, below is simplified for brevity

       vm.model.meta.name = 'Daniel';
       vm.nextTick(function() {
           vm.$el.textContent === 'Daniel';
       };

    }

});
```

Loaded HTML

```
<!-- template.html -->
<template v-if="model.meta">
    <header>
        <h1>{{ model.meta.name }}</h1>
    </header>
</template>
```

I'm not understanding how to use vue.nextTick() to update the vue model and make it reactive.  The documentation shows setting the property, then immediately calling Vue.nextTick() to update it.

I'm not sure what the **textContent** property of $el is and cannot find it simply googling.  Is it updating all text within brackets within the root element?

Edit: Added HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue: Reactive</title>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Reactive Vue</h1>
</header>

<main id="app"></main>

<script src="./app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) gets and sets the text contents of a DOM node. You should not need to directly manipulate the DOM for what you are doing.

Your assignment

```
   vm.model = buildObjectByArray(modelStructureAsArray);
```

should be sufficient to update the component. Since `model` is a `data` item, it is reactive, and assignment to it is a reactive operation. Setting its members, though, as in

```
   vm.model.meta.name = 'Daniel';
```

runs into a [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) since `name` wasn't present in the assigned structure. So instead, use

```
vm.$set(vm.model.meta, 'name', 'Daniel');
```

and the update will be reactive. You don't need to do anything with `$nextTick` for this. An example is below. Incidentally, you might as well put your code in the `created` hook rather than the jQuery `$`.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      model: {}
    };
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      vm.model = {
        meta: {},
        data: {
          details: {}
        }
      }
      vm.$set(vm.model.meta, 'name', 'Daniel');
    }, 500);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-if="model.meta">
    <header>
        <h1>{{ model.meta.name }}</h1>
    </header>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: I got an error that model was not set using vm.$set(model.meta), so I had to use vm.model.meta,  I can see that this updates the data in the Vue dev tools, but it is still not reacting within the page.

Comment: As a follow-up, how would I implement AJAX with this?  Would I put an .ajax/.load in the timeout function, or before it?  I need to load in the html template and then store the results from two json requests into the vue instance.

Comment: Instead of the timeout. I used timeout as a substitute for Ajax, because they're both asynchronous things you can put a callback in. Since you're loading the template, you may need to put your whole `new Vue` inside the ajax callback. Vue is going to use whatever is inside `#app` as its template. I presume you want to set that up before Vue sees it.